# update_post_meta using ajax

Tags: ajax

I have this code but its not working. How can i make it work thanks!

HTML:

```
<form id="updateAmountOffered" class="amountOffered" method="post" action="">

    <label for="amount">Amount Offered:</label>
    <div class="flex">
        <span class="currency">$</span>
        <input id="amount" class="inpAmount" type="text" maxlength="15" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updateAmountOffered" />
        <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">
        <span>
        <span>
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </span>
        <span>Accept</span>
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

PHP:

```
function updateAmountOffered(){

$amount = $_POST["inpAmount"];
$post_id = '27030';

update_post_meta($post_id, 'amount', $amount);

die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_updatemeta', 'updateAmountOffered');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updatemeta', 'updateAmountOffered');
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($, undefined) {

"use strict";

// When ready.
$(function() {

    var $form = $( "#updateAmountOffered" );
    var $input = $form.find( "input" );

    $input.on( "keyup", function( event ) {


        // When user select text in the document, also abort.
        var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
        if ( selection !== '' ) {
            return;
        }

        // When the arrow keys are pressed, abort.
        if ( $.inArray( event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39] ) !== -1 ) {
            return;
        }


        var $this = $( this );

        // Get the value.
        var input = $this.val();

        var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "");
                input = input ? parseInt( input, 10 ) : 0;

                $this.val( function() {
                    return ( input === 0 ) ? "" : input.toLocaleString( "en-US" );
                } );
       } );

    /**
     * ==================================
     * When Form Submitted
     * ==================================
     */
    $form.on( "submit", function( event ) {

        var $this = $( this );
        var arr = $this.serializeArray();

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i].value = arr[i].value.replace(/[($)\s\._\-]+/g, ''); // Sanitize the values.
        };

        $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/wp-admin/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
data: updateAmountOffered,
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){                                        
    console.error("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);                                                       
},
success: function(data) {                                       
    console.log("Hooray, it worked!");                                                                  
}                              
 });

        console.log( arr );

        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
 })(jQuery);
 </script>
```

Comment: This looks suspect: `data: updateAmountOffered`, I don't see where that gets set anywhere.

Comment: `data` needs to be an object that requires an action attribute with your function, that you want to call in wp-admin, so it should read: `data: {action: 'updatemeta'}` you could add more attributes in there, f.ex. a nonce to make a security check or some ID or whatever you like. try to google `wordpress ajax` and you'll find plenty of solutions that will get you started.. [this](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/) manual looks good for a start.. and your url looks weird too: 2 times `wp-admin` inside `/wp-admin/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`?

Comment: @honk31Thank you so much! The manual you gave me solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set a name attribute in your input tag with the id = "amount". Set the name as "inpAmount" and try again.

`<input id="amount" class="inpAmount" type="text" maxlength="15" />`

should be

`<input id="amount" class="inpAmount" type="text" maxlength="15" name="inpAmount" />`

As previously mentioned, the path to admin-ajax.php looks wrong as well.

The `wp_ajax` nomenclature is also incorrect. The actions suffix needs to match the value of the input with the name attribute set to "action."

Should be:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_updateAmountOffered', 'updateAmountOffered');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updateAmountOffered', 'updateAmountOffered');
```